# Cannot configure default E step for extruder on TH3D

Tags: marlin, creality-ender-3, firmware, th3d

I installed the TH3D firmware to my Ender 3 Pro yesterday and today I am trying to configure the extruder rate because I am not using the stock extruder on my printer but have swapped in a BMG extruder. I edited these values and upload it to my board

```
#define CUSTOM_ESTEPS
//#define REVERSE_E_MOTOR_DIRECTION
#define CUSTOM_ESTEPS_VALUE 415
```

But these values do not change when I start to print something and because of that I need to edit it manually by going in to tune menu and editing flow to 415. How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Initializing

After changing your firmware, you always need to overwrite the old values in the SRAM and EEPROM with those from the Firmware. Which you do with **[`M502 & M500`](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/a/11440/8884)**:

> Installing firmware does not by itself alter the EEPROM, so these settings needed to be *seeded into* SRAM via [`M502`](http://marlinfw.org/docs/gcode/M502.html) and then *saved* into EEPROM via [`M500`](http://marlinfw.org/docs/gcode/M500.html).

You could also run a G-code that has only these two lines:

```
M502
M500
```

### Altering the EEPROM

#### Via command

Alternatively, you could access the printer via a [terminal](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/q/10573/8884) and send the command [`M92 E415`](https://marlinfw.org/docs/gcode/M092.html) to overwrite the SRAM directly, then `M500` to save the new setting to EEPROM. The associated G-code that only alters the E-steps/mm would read

```
M92 E415
M500
```

#### Via Software

Or you use a terminal that supports direct alteration of the EEPROM, like Repetier Host.

Comment: Okay but what is the order should be. I am newbie and trying to understand. So am I going to send `M502` to printer then sending my edited values printer then sending `M500` to save values? is this the order? it is a bit confusing for now looking how to execute those commands and will try after I figure out hopefully. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Burak0015 Please follow the link on the `M50x` G-codes, you see that the order is loading from firmware first (`M502`) and than saving the values (`M500`).

Comment: Hopefully I did it, I connected printer via usb and send gcode via Cura. I sent gcode M502 ; reset! 
then I uploaded my values via arduino then I send gcode 
M500 ; saved!! 
hopefully it is correct.

Comment: @Burak0015 No, you first upload the firmware using Arduino or PlatformIO and then send `M502` followed directly by `M92 E415` and `M500`

Comment: what do you mean by send M502 followed directly by M92 E415 and M500? is it  must be one g-code like m502, m92, E415 or Can I send them one by one?

Comment: @Burak0015 Those are 2 variants: Install Firmware, send M502, then send M500. OR send M95 E415 then send M500.

Comment: Okay I will use first one  Install Firmware via arduino then send M502, then send M500 Thank you very much