# Does updating the firmware on an Ender 3 V2 erase its previous settings?

Tags: creality-ender-3, marlin

A few months ago, I flashed my Ender 3 V2 with [JyersUI](https://github.com/Jyers/Marlin) fork of the Marlin firmware and I like the options and settings that are available with this firmware. The author has put out another update (v1.3.4) and was curious if all my settings will be erased.

Does flashing the firmware erase all settings on the Ender 3 V2? If so, what settings should I record to update the new firmware once installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, settings are stored in memory (or the equivalent storage location).

When a new firmware is uploaded, the values set in the newly configured firmware can be set by `Restore Defaults` from the Marlin printer LCD the user interface. Alternatively, you could print a G-code file containing [`M502`](https://marlinfw.org/docs/gcode/M502.html) and [`M500`](https://marlinfw.org/docs/gcode/M500.html), or send them over using a [console](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/10573/what-is-a-printer-console-terminal).

> `M502`
> Reset all configurable settings to their factory defaults.
>
> To also reset settings in EEPROM, follow with M500.

> `M500`
> Save all configurable settings to EEPROM

See [M502 will reset all configurable settings to their "factory defaults", which settings are those?](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/11438/m502-will-reset-all-configurable-settings-to-their-factory-defaults-which-set) for more information.

[This answer](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/a/11440) hints to a similar description:

> Installing firmware does not by itself alter the EEPROM, so these settings needed to be seeded into SRAM via `M502` and then saved into EEPROM via `M500`.

Please note that the EEPROM on 32-bit boards are emulated. There are several ways to emulate EEPROM storage via flash storage in the ARM processor or using an SD card. There is a solution for an actual EEPROM, but that requires buying an EEPROM chip and breakout board on the I2C connector if it has such an output port. Selection of which is done in the `Configuration_adv.h` config file.

Comment: For verification of any changes, could I send an M503 to the printer before flashing the new firmware, save that to a .txt file, then flash the firmware, send another M503, save to another .txt file, and compare the two files for changes?