# Ender 3 Pro Beeping when Hot End Reaches 100 ºC

Tags: troubleshooting, creality, heating-element, mainboard

A little context might be important to troubleshoot this: Last year, I have changed the extruder and the entire hot end piece of my Ender 3 Pro. One day, while cleaning the nozzle with a metallic brush, something on it short circuited and this bricked my mainboard.

Recently, I have changed the broken 4.2.0 mainboard with a brand new 4.2.7 one. Everything seemed to be fine until I attempted to pre heat the nozzle again to 200 °C.

Every time the nozzle reaches around 100 °C the printer starts beeping loudly and resets continuously until the nozzle cools down to room temperature.

I have it connected to OctoPrint and I could see that there were no errors being logged apart from it saying that there was no SD card and no EEPROM.

What can I do to further troubleshoot this error? Is there anything from the OctoPrint side that could provide more information?

Answer (score 2):

A firmware is configured with settings which are stored in the chip called EEPROM. EEPROM  is short for Electrically Erasable Programmable Read-Only Memory which is a kind of non-volatile memory (see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EEPROM)). It is the chip thar stores the firmware settings you generally see when you command the `M503` G-code (see [M502 will reset all configurable settings to their "factory defaults", which settings are those?](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/11438/m502-will-reset-all-configurable-settings-to-their-factory-defaults-which-set)) in a terminal ([What is a printer console/terminal?](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/10573/what-is-a-printer-console-terminal)).

The Creality controller board V4.2.7, with a 32-bit microprocessor (most 32-bit microprocessors do not have a EEPROM), stores the data on an SD card, not in the EEPROM. But, the firmware thinks that the EEPROM is used, it is merely a file on the SD card. This could hint to the errors that you are receiving.

To solve this, you need to insert a working SD card (format the SD card as FAT32) in the machine and keep it there.